# filter pandas data on specific index

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

I'd like to filter a dataframe based on specifics index.
I've read things about query but I don't succeed.

Here is the code which create my pivot table. I'd like to filter on specific members

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(my_dataframe)
    table = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Date","member","Card"], columns=["Type"],values=["Heure"],aggfunc=[len]) #,fill_value=0)
    table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='TcD')
```

What should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some data sample with expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) or select by level of `MultiIndex` by [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Card':list('baaaaa'),
                   'Date':['2017-10-01'] * 6,
                   'Heure':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'Type':[5,5,5,9,5,9],
                   'member':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
  Card        Date  Heure  Type member
0    b  2017-10-01      1     5      a
1    a  2017-10-01      3     5      a
2    a  2017-10-01      5     5      a
3    a  2017-10-01      7     9      b
4    a  2017-10-01      1     5      b
5    a  2017-10-01      0     9      b
```

---

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["Date","member","Card"], 
                       columns="Type",
                       values="Heure",
                       aggfunc='size')
print (table)
Type                      5    9
Date       member Card          
2017-10-01 a      a     2.0  NaN
                  b     1.0  NaN
           b      a     1.0  2.0

table1 = table.query('member == "a"')
print (table1)
Type                      5   9
Date       member Card         
2017-10-01 a      a     2.0 NaN
                  b     1.0 NaN

idx = pd.IndexSlice
table1 = table.loc[idx[:,'a',:],:]
print (table1)
Type                      5   9
Date       member Card         
2017-10-01 a      a     2.0 NaN
                  b     1.0 NaN
```

EDIT:

For filter by multiple values use:

```
table1 = table.query('member in ["a", "b"]')
print (table1)
Type                      5    9
Date       member Card          
2017-10-01 a      a     2.0  NaN
                  b     1.0  NaN
           b      a     1.0  2.0

idx = pd.IndexSlice
table1 = table.loc[idx[:,['a', 'b'],:],:]
print (table1)
Type                      5    9
Date       member Card          
2017-10-01 a      a     2.0  NaN
                  b     1.0  NaN
           b      a     1.0  2.0
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine for one member, but what is the syntax for more than 1 member ?  (I don't understand the structure of idx)

Comment: @Eric _ added solution for filter by multiple values. `idx` is common used for slicing by `MultiIndex`, check [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers), `In[52]`

Comment: Great my misunderstanding was du to encoding ... I have (é) in one of the index